# Complex HTML/CSS Sticky Double Sidebar Layout

Tags: html, css

I've been staring at this wireframe I've made and it has me stumped on how to make it...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytiMf.png

[image: Screenshot]

The sticky jquery properties are not the problem, it's the positioning of the areas themselves given their overlapping nature that's giving me strife.

Any suggestions? Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Fv64/

```
<div class="green">Hi</div>
<div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="yellow">Hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="red">Stuff</div>
        <div class="purple">And</div>
        <div class="black">Things</div>
    </div>
</div>
```